# Remove jQuery from Wordpress except for one specific page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using the following code to remove jQuery completely from my WP site for better performance:

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', false);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

I would, however, like to load jQuery back up on one specific page, say myimaginarysite.com/jQueryNeeded to be able to use Fluentforms one that page.

I've found tons of examples on how to completely remove it but nothing on how to remove it except for specific pages. Can this be done?

Comment: Add it manually: ie add a `<script src="...link to jquery...">` to that page

Comment: Is my suggested answer works for you?

Answer (score 0):

By the using [is_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

```
    function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin() && !is_page('your-page-slug')) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', false);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```